# can I force ruby not to trim my string?

Tags: ruby, string, trim

[Qualification Round Africa 2010 Problem C. T9 Spelling](https://code.google.com/codejam/contest/351101/dashboard#s=p2)

I am learning ruby from doing some exercise in Google Code Jam.
in this question. It will give me some input as follow.

```
3 
hello
hello world
 hello
```

and convert these string in to T9 input format.

so firstly, I read the files to an array line by line as follow:

```
IO.foreach(fileName) do |line|
    inputs << line.strip
end
```

then I loop each line using the following codes:

```
start = 1;
inputs[0].to_i.times do |i|
  words = inputs[start]
# puts "words : #{words} length: #{words.length}"
end
```

and the output become like this

```
words : hello length: 5
words : hello world length: 11
words : hello length: 5
```

it automatically trim the leading space of the third " hello".
any idea?

Comment: Then don't call `strip` in `inputs << line.strip`.

Comment: @YuHao: "Doctor, it hurts when I do this" - "Then don't do this" :)

Comment: @YuHao oops... thanks... what a stupid mistake..

Answer (score 1):

If you want to stop trimming any whitespace at all, then change

```
inputs << line.strip
```

to

```
inputs << line
```

and all your whitespace will be preserved.

If you want to stop trimming whitespace on the left side only, change it to

```
inputs << line.rstrip
```

and it will trim only right-side whitespace.